# yocto - edit file in rootimage with no permission

Tags: linux, root, yocto

I am working with the yocto project and a Raspberry Pi 0 with wifi. I want to integrate the wpa_supplicant.conf file and copy it to the /etc/ folder. 
My recipe fails with reason stating that I don't have permission to copy this file at this location.

I am using do_install_append, but it did not work

do_install_append() {
             install -m 0755 ${S}/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/
             install -m 0755 ${S}/interaces /etc/network/
}

I tried copy -f but it failed also, nevertheless I tried sudo, but no clue.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your wpa_supplicant.conf file directly on the root of the /boot partition of your SD-card.

The Pi will move it to the right location and start using it.

This overwrites your old config, so do a backup first.

I usually put the wpa_supplicant.conf there immediately after writing the image to the card. I usually put an empty file named ssh there too, and that enables SSH.

That way it connects to WiFi on first boot with SSH enabled.

The /boot partition is the one formatted as vfat/fat/fat32.

Comment: The operating system will use `/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` immediately, not only on next boot.

Comment: (^.^)d  (very good)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a folder first for the etc and then for the network

using the following
             install -d ${D}/etc
             install -d ${D}/etc/network